# Find last true element of columns

Tags: matlab, indexing

I'd like to extract one value per column of a matrix using a condition. Multiple values on each column match that condition, but only the last one should be selected. It is safe to assume that each row contains at least one such value.

So given an NxM matrix and an equally-sized boolean, extract M values for which the boolean is true and it is the last true value in a column. For example:

```
m = magic(4);
i = (m > 10);

% m =
% 16     2     3    13
%  5    11    10     8
%  9     7     6    12
%  4    14    15     1

% i =
% 1   0   0   1
% 0   1   0   0
% 0   0   0   1
% 0   1   1   0
```

And the expected output:

```
% i_ =
% 1   0   0   0
% 0   0   0   0
% 0   0   0   1
% 0   1   1   0

% x = [16, 14, 15, 12]
```

I know this could be easily achieved by looping through the columns and using `find`, but in my experience there often are better ways of formulating these problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do it

```
m(max(i.*reshape([1:numel(m)],size(m))))
```

---

**Explanation**

So we are generating an array of indices

```
reshape([1:numel(m)],size(m))

ans =

1    5    9   13
2    6   10   14
3    7   11   15
4    8   12   16
```

That represents the indices for each value. The we multiply that with `I` to get the values we are interested in

```
i.*reshape([1:numel(m)],size(m))
ans =

1    0    0   13
0    6    0    0
0    0    0   15
0    8   12    0
```

Then we do a `max` on that since `max` works on columns. This will give us the last index in each column.

```
max(i.*reshape([1:numel(m)],size(m)))
ans =

1    8   12   15
```

Then apply those indices on `m` to get the values

```
m(max(i.*reshape([1:numel(m)],size(m))))
ans =

   16   14   15   12
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the second output of [max](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) to find the last true element of each column. Before that the logical matrx should be multiplied by an increasing column vector.

```
[~, idx] = max((1:size(i, 1)).' .* i, [], 1, 'linear') ;
x = m(idx) ;
```

Comment: What does "linear" do? It's not mentioned in the reference page. And couldn't this be simplified to `max((1:size(i, 1)).' .* i)`?

Comment: Without linear the max function returns the row index of maximum elements. But linear returns the true index. There is an example in the reference page for it.

Comment: I [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60153982/3978545) my answer which used exactly this approach because I didn't know about the `'linear'` argument and a call to `sub2ind` felt like a bodge! Thanks for the tip

Comment: It shows your care about the quality of your posts. However I have seen in SO persons that don't bother correcting or deleting their post after they are noticed that they are in a wrong way. If you reopen that post I will be  one of upvoters. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way, using [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[~, col] = find(i); % column indices
lin = find(i); % linear indices
x = accumarray(col, m(lin), [], @(x) x(end));
```

Comment: accumarray == MATLAB's Swiss Army knife.

Comment: @rahnema1 Indeed! :-)